# NGINX Client Certificate with Indirect CRL

Tags: nginx, openssl, crl, client-certificate

I'm trying to implement mTLS using Nginx SSL Module. Everything works fine until I give Nginx CRL files concatenated in PEM format because one of the CRL is an Indirect CRL.

The chain for a leaf certificate will look like this:

```
Root -> CA1 -> CA2 -> CA3 -> Leaf
```

But in my use case, CA2 and CA3 will not be able to issue CRL so CA1 signs a CRL Issuer. This CRL Issuer will issue CRL for revoked CA3 certificates and Leaf certificates.
CA3 and Leaf certs contain the CRL Issuer DN in the CDP, and the CRL file is correctly format with the CRL Extension "Distribution Point" with indirectCRL=true and each revoked certifcate in the list contains its issuer DN in the right CRL Entry extension.

I can verify the revocation of a certificate using OpenSSL but with the option "untrusted".

```
$ openssl verify -crl_check -extended_crl -CAfile chain.pem -CRLfile concatcrl.pem -untrusted crlissuer.pem leafcert.pem
```

But I'm unable to do the same verification with Nginx:

```
client SSL certificate verify error: (3:unable to get certificate CRL) while reading client request headers
```

My Nginx configuration is:

```
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/clients-cert/crlissuer.pem;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/clients-cert/root+ca1.pem;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 10;
ssl_crl /var/crl/chain-crl.pem;
```

(The client will send its leaf cert + CA3 + CA2).

If I comment the directive "ssl_crl", my client can connect to the server.
I also tried  different combinations of ssl_trusted_certificate and ssl_client_certificate by adding the crlissuer.pem to the chain, the chain in both directive with the CRL issuer..

I don't see other way to resolve this issue. Please help.

Comment: You probably can't as indirect CRLs aren't well supported.  I would concentrate efforts on getting Root, CA1 and CA2 to issue CRLs.  What's the reason they can't at the moment?

Comment: Thanks @garethTheRed. Root and CA1 will issue CRL. CA2 and CA3 could be considered as offline. And I'm talking about dozens of thousands of certificates.

Comment: Then it might be wise to reconsider your PKI design - it would probably easier than trying to get indirect CRL to work in practice!  If CA3 can issue thousands of certificates, it can issue CRLs (or integrate with an OCSP service).  The same can be said of CA2.